# modify json data in php laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I've a sample json data

```
{
   "cities": {
          "total": 100,
          "count":5000,
          "cities_list" : [{
                 "name": "city1",
                 "count": 1000
          },
           {
                 "name": "city2",
                 "count": 2000
           }
          ]
   }


}
```

How can I append the `cities_list` array directly to `cities` which would look like

```
{
     "cities": [{
           "name": "city1",
           "count": 1000
      },
      {
           "name": "city2",
           "count": 2000 
      }
     ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share PHP code? Like how are you getting the data and what variables do you store them in?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a piece where I got stuck on. As I dont have much knowledge on Json, I posted here. basically, this is a response coming from repository function with mysql db.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, about all the stuff, but i assume your "json" or just associative array is in variable (for example `foo`)

Now you should set:

```php
$foo["cities"] = $foo["citites"]["citites_list"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your JSON result is stored in a variable called `$results`

```
$results = json_decode($results,true); //convert json to array
    
$modifiedArray= [];

$modifiedArray= $results['cities']['cities_list']->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return ['cities'][][
        'name' => $item->name,
        'count' => $item->count
    ];
});
```

This is more of a laravel approach since you also tagged laravel. Your modified array is an `array` type if you want to be a JSON again you have to encode it into a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unset function

```
$data= json_decode($your_json);
$json_arr = json_decode($your_json, true);   

unset($data->total);
unset($json_arr['total']);
```